# Convert from PolynomialRing to other PolynomialRing in SageMath

Tags: sage

I have three algebraic structures in SageMath and I would like to convert them into each other

1. `Z(3*7681) mod x^768 - x^384 + 1`
2. `Z(7681) mod x^768 - x^384 + 1`
3. `Z(3) mod x^768 - x^384 + 1`

I would like to do this:

> f = [object of type 2]
>
> f = f^-1 (f is invertible)
>
> //convert f to type 1
>
> //do some calculations with f
>
> //convert f to type 3 (all coefficients mod 3)

I tested change_ring function and I tried to use modulo operator for typ 1 to 3. Is there a "convert"-function?

Here is how I defined the fields in Sage

```
R1.<r> = PolynomialRing(IntegerModRing(7681*3), 'r').quotient(x^768 - x^384 + 1)
R2.<s> = PolynomialRing(GF(7681), 's').quotient(x^768 - x^384 + 1)
R3.<t> = PolynomialRing(GF(3), 't').quotient(x^768 - x^384 + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the three quotient rings of polynomial rings:

```
sage: x = polygen(ZZ)
sage: R1.<r> = PolynomialRing(Zmod(7681*3), 'r').quotient(x^768 - x^384 + 1)
sage: R2.<s> = PolynomialRing(GF(7681), 's').quotient(x^768 - x^384 + 1)
sage: R3.<t> = PolynomialRing(GF(3), 't').quotient(x^768 - x^384 + 1)
```

Define an element f2 in R2:

```
sage: f2 = 875*s^5 + 5355*s^4 + 6859*s^3 + 3073*s^2 + 2552*s + 1626
```

Map it to R1 and from there to R3:

```
sage: f1 = R1(f2.list())
sage: f3 = R3(f1.list())
```

Check the result:

```
sage: f3
2*t^5 + t^3 + t^2 + 2*t
```